# Bootstrap 4 - Flex vertical align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm using bootstrap 4 flex box to create a vertical align however I still have the age old problem where my row, and column don't expand to be the full height of the container. Therefore my vertical align flex box code isn't going to work because the container is only as high as the content.

As the hero class is set to 70vh, I want the content to be vertically aligned within that container. So the `H2`, `P`, & `a` tags are centred vertically within that hero wrapper using the new bootstrap flex grid layout

Do I have to set a min-height in order to resolve this issue?

```css
.hero {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css"/>

<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-items-xs-middle">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <h2>a real tag line here</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce iaculis dapibus enim, ut pharetra magna venenatis non. Maecenas aliquam.</p>
        <a class="tek-btn" href="#">Order now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7qynca6z/

Comment: "problem where my row, and column don't expand to be the full height of the container" -- How much height do you need the container div to take?

Comment: The full height the hero is 70vh, so I would like the content to be vertically aligned within that container. Sorry I'll update the question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `hero` a flexbox and give it `align-items: center`.

See demo below and [`Updated fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/mLkt4crd/):

```css
.hero {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css"/>

<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-items-xs-middle">
      <div class="col-xs">
        <h2>a real tag line here</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce iaculis dapibus enim, ut pharetra magna venenatis non. Maecenas aliquam.</p>
        <a class="tek-btn" href="#">Order now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an **updated** solution using the latest Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6).
**No extra CSS required**.

https://www.codeply.com/go/hFtD71FMc4

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs">
        <h2>a real tag line here</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce iaculis dapibus enim, ut pharetra magna venenatis non. Maecenas aliquam.</p>
           <a class="tek-btn" href="#">Order now!</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```